# Can you cleanup the "Users" folder in Windows 7 from information/saved data whose corresponding application has been removed?

Tags: windows-7, disk-cleanup

After a lot of installations of various applications in my machine, various folders are created in the Users/*myusername* folder. After I have removed most of my applications last week, there are still folders with saved data in My Documents, AppData etc. Unfortunately, I did not use a dedicated software like Revo Uninstaller that searches for extra files/registry entries and removes them during the uninstall process.

The question is: is there any application (or script but I guess that's pretty hard to exist) that can cleanup your "Users" folder and remove any directories that do not have their corresponding application installed? I know that there are settings there that you may want to keep in case that you reinstall the software, but I do not want to keep them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of  program that would clean the folders for you, however if you want to clean the **registry** from all the entries that became useless I would use **CCleaner**. As for the folders you can delete them manually, there shouldn't be that many.

Comment: For registry there are a lot of different tools including some dedicated ones that can do the job. The problem is the hundreds of folders that I need to remove, and I cannot identify which ones should and which ones should not be removed since they are named after the company etc. It would take me more than a couple of hours to do that on 4 machines and I want to know if there is an easier way.

Comment: @F1234k I don't think there is such a program since the folders that are left are not dependent on anything at this point. A half manual solution could be to go through the folders on one computer and create a batch file that you could run on the other computers. This will work if all the machines had the same softwares installed.